# Open source theme/plugin directory engine

Tags: open-source, plugins, content-management-system, directory, themes

Most open source wiki and CMS engines host user-contributed themes/plugins in directories whose code, strikingly, is not itself released as open source software. Possibly the best example is WordPress' own [plugin/theme directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), offering support for one-click plugin installation as well as plugin metadata, screenshots, changelogs, system requirements information, community rating, categories/tags and so on. The WordPress plugin directory is built on a collection of open source software and works as an interface to an SVN repository, allowing contributors to self-maintain their code.

Is anyone aware of an open source engine with similar features to allow the hosting and community-driven maintenance of themes and plugins?

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org) is open source and hosts community driven themes and modules.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) is a great way to set up your own extensibility framework.  But, it won't be a turnkey solution.  You will need to tailor it to your application by providing the interfaces that the plugins will have to implement.